# C# ASP.NET Signalr OnConnected OnDisconnected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, signalr

Во время разработки возникла проблема, и есть подозрения что метод OnDisconnected может вызваться асинхронно до того как завершится метод OnConnected, может ли такое быть? И если да, то есть способ их как-то синхронизировать, чтобы OnDisconnected вызывался после OnConnected?

Comment: `метод OnDisconnected может вызваться асинхронно до того как завершится метод OnConnected` это было бы довольно странно :)

Comment: а, стоп. Ну да, вы ведь можете `OnConnected` вообще сделать бесконечным, тогда да, логично